# How to write x bytes at a time from a string with write()?

Tags: python

I'm writing a program for an internet module that reads a locally stored file, and writes it to a .txt file on my computer.

```
def write2file():
    print "Listing local files ready for copying:"
    listFiles()
    print 'Enter name of file to copy:'
    name = raw_input()
    pastedFile = readAll('AT+URDFILE="' + name + '"')    #Reads a local file using AT commands (not important to discuss)
    print 'Enter path to file directory'
    path = raw_input()
    myFile = open(join(path, name),"w")
    myFile.write(pastedFile)
    myFile.close()
```

I write the whole thing in one go. Problem is that when the product is implemented, it's only going to be possible to write 128 bytes at a time.

Comment: Please update your question with your code that attempts to `write 128 bytes at a time.`

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand this `Problem is that when the product is implemented, it's only going to be possible to write 128 bytes at a time` ?

Comment: I think the part marked `no need to discuss` *might* need discussion. If you are indeed looking to write from a stream, the [`io`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) module might be helpful. You can use `StringIO` or `BytesIO` to stream a specific amount of content

Comment: I've posted to give some clarity on the `io` comment, it's still unclear what `readAll` does

Comment: What was meant was that after implementation the communication will happen through a protocol which only allows messages up to 128 bytes at a time. I want to test a communication scenario, which is why I needed the program to write 128 bytes at a time instead of the whole string. Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write from a stream, the `io` module can help nicely here. I'm assuming you do *not* want to write bytes to a file, so we will use the `StringIO` object, which will treat a string object like a file handler

```py
from io import StringIO

def write2file(bytes_to_write):
    print "Listing local files ready for copying:"
    listFiles()
    print 'Enter name of file to copy:'
    name = raw_input()
    pastedFile = readAll('AT+URDFILE="' + name + '"')

    # I'm assuming pastedFile is a `string` object
    str_obj = StringIO(pastedFile)

    # Now we can read in specific bytes-sizes from str_obj
    fh = open(os.path.join(path, name), 'w')

    # read in the first bit, bytes_to_write is an int for number of bytes you want to read
    bit = str_obj.read(bytes_to_write)

    while bit:
        fh.write(bit)
        bit = str_obj.read(bytes_to_write)

    fh.close()
```

The way this works is `StringIO` will `read` x number of bytes until it hits the end of the string, then it will return a null string, which will terminate the `while` loop.

The cleaner way to do file opening and closing is using the `with` keyword:

```py
   with open(filename, w) as fh:
       # read in the first bit, bytes_to_write is an int for number of bytes you want to read
       bit = str_obj.read(bytes_to_write)

       while bit:
           fh.write(bit)
           bit = str_obj.read(bytes_to_write)
```

That way you don't need the explicit `open` and `close` commands

NOTE:
This is assuming the `readAll` function does indeed read the entire file that you've given it. The *only reads 128 bytes at a time* might call that into question